# Loading negative values into RISC-V

Tags: assembly, riscv

I have an assignment where I have to load values into register s7 and everything is working fine until I get to -2999.` xor s7, s7, s7    # Clear s7
addi s7, s7, 29   # Add 29 to s7

```
# b. -214
xor s7, s7, s7    # Clear s7
addi s7, s7, -214 # Add -214 to s7

# c. -2999
xor s7, s7, s7    # Clear s7
addi s7, s7, -2999 # Add -2999 to s7`
```

When the code executes to put -2999 into the register it loads 1097. I am not too sure what I am doing wrong. Could someone provide some insight please?

Comment: `addi` only supports 12 bit immediates. Your assembler should have produced a warning or error, such as `Error: illegal operands 'addi s7,s7,-2999'`

Comment: Many assemblers I have worked with would silently truncate the immediate. It looks like that's probably what's happening here.

Comment: `xor s7, s7, s7` is an inefficient way to zero a register; xor-zeroing is *only* good on x86.  On RISC-V it's required to have a dependency on the old value of s7 (for `memory_order_consume` / memory dependency-ordering reasons).  If you want to add an immediate to zero to get a consant, use `addi s7, x0, -214`.  RISC-V has a zero register instead of a mov-immediate instruction.  Also, just use `li s7, -2999` to let the assembler invent a 2-instruction sequence that works.  Use a disassembler to see what it picked.

Comment: Try `li s7, -2999` and then look to see what the assembler generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`addi` instruction](https://msyksphinz-self.github.io/riscv-isadoc/html/rvi.html#addi) has a sign-extended 12-bit field for the immediate. `-2999` doesn't fit into 12 bits. You need to do this in two steps or use a different method entirely.